# href link with phpmailer is erased

Tags: email, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send an email with a button that has a link to another page. For some reason it works almost everytime, except with one specific client of mine. Apperantly his email has is hotmail or outlook.
What happens in this case is that the button comes with a blanked link.

The following peace of code might help:

```
     $mensagem .= '<br><div><!--[if mso]>
                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="8%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#b1cef1">
                <w:anchorlock/>
                <center>[enter image description here][1]
                <![endif]-->
                <a href="http://conazweb.com.br/follow-up/'.$opcao1_file.'"
                style="background-color:#b1cef1;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;
                font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;
                text-decoration:none;width:300px;margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">COMPRAR VIA CONAZ</a>
                <!--[if mso]>
                </center>
                </v:roundrect>
                <![endif]--></div>';
```

By doing a code inspection on the button on the case that the problem is occuring I got the following code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtyhtrvdk0nas5d/Inspection%20button.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient [Microsoft VML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language), essentially nothing uses it any more, and support has even been dropped from Internet Explorer. If you want links to work, use plain links, which you can style to [look like buttons](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
What I didn't understand is that your link on "look like buttons" gives me an explanation that it is ok to use VML (support wise). The only problem it says it can be time-consuming or having design limitations.

Comment: It doesn't say that. When you use vml it is only rendered in outlook, and all other browsers use the html fallback, but in your code you are not providing a fallback, so you end up with nothing.